# Column render, listen to click event of a <i> tag

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a render function on a grid column that basically returns some html, the html consists of a `<i>` tag to display an icon and then some text. Sort of like this:

```
 <i class="some class"> </i> some text
```

I only want to attach a click event to the `<i>` tag, not the text, so itemClick wouldn't work. How do I attach an element listener just to the `<i>` tag that is returned from my render function ?

I did look at use a columnaction but I can only use an img, and no text can be set after the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the cellclick event, then check the event target:

```
listeners: {
    cellclick: function(grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
        if (cellIndex === whatever && Ext.fly(e.target).hasCls('foo')) {
             // Go
        }
    }
}
```